# Very slow querying in Access, Can a SQL server do any better

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access

I am working on MSAccess to quickly load the data and perform some analysis.
Since the data exceeds over 200,000 records, it gets really very slow and takes for ever or never returns a result. I know that this is expected.

Does installing a SQL server (freely availalbe) like MySQL do better in this scenario?
(even for a million similar records)

I cannot ask for paid software to perform analysis.

Comment: 200,000 is not a lot. Very slow is not to be expected. Have you optimized your query? Have you got indexes? Is your backebd on a server? SQL Server is not a cure-all.

Comment: There are freely available editions of Microsoft SQL Server as well as MySQL.

Comment: Agreed with @Remou, 200k records shouldn't take very long to query -- more likely, your query is inefficient.  If you're just going to be running MySQL or SQL Server on the same box that you're running Access, and using the same inefficient query, you probably WON'T see much of a speed increase.

Comment: As Remou noted, Indexes are crutial if you are doing ordering or trying to search your data. An old database I inherited the user instructions said to enter the search terms and then wait several minutes. I added an index and now it takes several seconds. Something else you may want to try is from the Database Tools tab, Analyze Performance. Access may recommend changes that may improve the speed of your queries etc, which can be implemented via a button.

Comment: Its not a lot, and I haven't added indexes in MS Access. (I will try that). Also, backend? - just MSAcess and accessing it directly, And i have a relatively older machine.. (dual code processor 2.33GHz, 2GB ram)

Comment: The comment regarding a backend has to do with a split database where your forms, queries, and reports are in one file and the data is in another. But since the database is for your own personal use, this likely wouldn't be done and may not be advisible.

Comment: @Daniel The question about backend is to do with slow connections to the server :)

Comment: @Remou, Daniel Cook: thanks for pointing out, and indexes really helped me a lot here. The query is inefficient because of the absense of the indexes, it worked in under a second after creating the required indexes.

Comment: Tada :) I am glad it worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not talking about a whole lot of records. Installing SQL Lite won't do much for you if the query you are using is not optimized for performance. I recommend attempting to optimize your query and/or increasing the query timeout so results can be returned. Indexing your tables will also slightly improve performance, but the query optimization is the big thing.

Comment: @Remou answered by query.. but cannot mark as correct answer there. (Marking correct, and indexes helped me fix it)